# Track Page Views with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-analytics

I have created an online magazine (that I hope will take off someday) using wordpress. I would like to be able to track the number of page views of each item without using a wordpress plugin.

What is the best solution??

Should I use jQuery to track page views and then insert that data into a custom wordpress table?

Or is it possible to use google analytics and then gather the require information from that?

Note: I will use the information to display 'Popular Posts', 'Top Categories', etc. on the site.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this is something that requires a server-side solution, so I'm not sure what jQuery can really do for you (other than possibly make the presentation of the page view data more interesting, I guess).

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with JQuery, you basically want to book keep desired info (mostly already stored in the wordpress db) and do data mining. If you prefer to do this client side, you are basically creating your own analytics script (like google analytics), unless you know what you are doing, I would urge you to use a plugin or write some script to look up the db and web log to analyze.

Comment: From what Ive understood (and by no means do I think I'm right) that javascript can be very useful in tracking page views. Therefore, I figured that jQuery would be my best bet. I guess my real question is: how do I track clicks/page views??

Comment: Thanks to whoever down voted me for asking a question - I didn't know that was a bad thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use jQuery; Google Analytics will track all pages, as well as entry and exit URLs. You'll have more info than you can use.

As for popular posts and categories, why reinvent the wheel?: [WordPress › Most Popular Posts « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/most-popular-posts/) or any number of other plugins and widgets.

**Edit 2/26/10:**

Your question was probably downvoted because you're not clear about why you want to use jQuery, and you're confusing a perceived need for Ajax with a need to count page views and display popular posts and categories.

You're going to spend far more time creating a plugin or code to do what you want than using what's already out there. The popular post and category plugins have tens of thousands of downloads, and I doubt that they are bloated and buggy. Search the [WordPress Support Forums](http://wordpress.org/support/)  or check a plugin's author's own forums for help with a plugin. And if you do want to write your own code, it's a good idea to start with some code that already exists in the form of a plugin or code available in the forums.

Comment: Most of the wordpress plugins are bloated, buggy, and do not completely suit my needs. I honestly just want to create a very simple and clean way of tracking page views.